# Problem with routing in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

My routes.rb files has sty like this:

```
    match 'tickets/:conditions'           => 'tickets#index', :as => :list_tickets, :constraints => {:conditions => /(\w+):(\w+)\/?/}
    match 'tickets/sort::sort'            => 'tickets#index', :as => :root_sort
    match 'tickets/mailbox::mailbox'      => 'tickets#index', :as => :view_mailbox
    match 'tickets/status::status'        => 'tickets#index', :as => :view_status  
    match 'tickets/tag::tag'              => 'tickets#index', :via => :get, :as => :show_tag
```

I want to get it working with addresses like:
http://localhost:3000/tickets/mailbox:1/sort:date
and inverted too:
http://localhost:3000/tickets/sort:date/mailbox:1

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry that I cannot give you a detailed and tested answer (lack of time, at the moment), but I suppose you may find [Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) guide helpful, especially the section [Route globbing](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing).

If you write (*beware! I haven't tested this code*):

```
match 'tickets/*conditions' => 'tickets#index'
```

then in your action you may parse the `params[:conditions]` and apply necessary filters.
Something like:

```
params[:conditions].split('/').map {|c| c.split(':',2) }
# => [ ['sort','date'], ['mailbox','1'] ]
```

I'm afraid you will not have the named routes for all the possible conditions, but I hope it is not very important. I am sure you will handle the problem how to create the path with given conditions - just remember about calling `CGI::escape` on the necessary parts.